# Script to copy and paste range from current sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I have been using to copy and past a range of cells on a specific sheet. It works great, but how can I make the same script work on multiple sheets?

```
function dcopy1() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

// Copy from 177th row, 9th column 
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(177, 9, 17, 1).getValues();

//Paste to 5th row, 3rd column
sheetTo.getRange(5,3,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Comment: Hey which is static (from or to) sheets? Or are both your source (from) sheet and your input (to) sheet dynamic?

Comment: The source sheet and input sheet are the same. What I would like the script to do the exact same thing, but on the active sheet I am currently looking at. @Nami888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey since u want to copy the values from the **same sheet** from source location to destination location:

```
function dcopy1() {
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

// Copy from 177th row, 9th column 
var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange(177, 9, 17, 1).getValues();

//Paste to 5th row, 3rd column
sheetTo.getRange(5,3,valuesToCopy.length,1).setValues(valuesToCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Copy multiple sheets

```
function dcopy1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shto = ss.getSheetByName("MasterSheet");
  const incl = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];//sheets to include by name
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => incl.includes(s.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let vs = sh.getRange(177, 9, 17, 1).getValues();
    if (shto.getLastRow() < 5) {
      shto.getRange(5, 3, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    } else {
      shto.getRange(shto.getLastRow() + 1, 3, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: returns an error:


TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of null
(anonymous) @ Untitled.gs:7
dcopy1 @ Untitled.gs:5

Comment: Perhaps your sheet names and my sheet names are different

Comment: Were all supposed to be programmers here.  Sometimes you have to be able to look at the code and see if it makes sense for your particular need

Comment: The problem is, this script sources from a MasterSheet, but I want it to copy data from the active sheet itself to the same sheet. The input comes from a specific range, and it's needs to be pasted into another specific range, regardless of what might already be there. So, the script you provided doesn't do either.

Comment: When I ran the script earlier, I kept the "MasterSheet" reference - and that's what caused the error. When I changed it, the script copied from the correct range, but it pasted the range at the bottom of the sheet, instead of row 5 column 3.